# pgAdmin is throwing Error saving properties unable to connect server timeout expired connecting to Postgresql in AWS Lightsail

Tags: postgresql, timeout, pgadmin-4, amazon-lightsail

I have a Linux instance in AWS Lightsail and I have started up a PostgreSQL database on my LightSail hosted Linux server. On my local Windows 10 machine, I have a Postgresql server as well. When I am attempting to connect to the AWS Postgresql server on Lightsail following the steps described here:

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-connecting-to-your-postgres-database

On my pgAdmin (my pgAdmin is acting as the client while the Postgresql database that I have on AWS is the server), I am seeing the following error message:

```
Error saving properties
Unable to connect to the server:

timeout expired
```

Please note, my database is hosted by Lightsail and *not* by AWS RDS.

Answer (score 0):

1. use SSL tunnel with your ip and pem file under SSH Tunnel Tab
2. Under connection user the ip 127.0.0.1 with your postgres username and password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).